# How do I convert this Informix nested join to a tsql nested join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, informix, outer-join

I'm having a real hard time with this conversion. Those nested OUTER joins are a first to me.

Original Informix query:

```
from    ttdpur401105 tdpur401
,   ttdpur400105 tdpur400

-- Problem is here
, outer tarpur002105 arpur002
, outer (ttdpur402105 tdpur402, outer  (ttisfc001105 tisfc001 , outer ttcibd001105 tcibd001a )) 
, outer ttcibd001105 tcibd001 
-- Problem is here

WHERE   tdpur401.t_otbp = ' WD005' 
and ((tdpur401.t_oltp=1 AND tdpur401.t_qibo <>0) OR(tdpur401.t_oltp=4 AND tdpur401.t_qibo = 0 AND tdpur401.t_qidl<>tdpur401.t_qoor)) 
and     tdpur401.t_fire <> 1
and     tdpur401.t_orno = tdpur400.t_orno 
and (tdpur400.t_hdst<>25 AND tdpur400.t_hdst<>30 AND tdpur400.t_hdst<>40) 
and arpur002.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno 
and arpur002.t_pono = tdpur401.t_pono 
and tdpur402.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno 
and tdpur402.t_pono = tdpur402.t_pono 
and tisfc001.t_pdno = tdpur402.t_pdno 
and tcibd001.t_item = tdpur401.t_item 
and tcibd001a.t_item = tisfc001.t_mitm 
and (tdpur401.t_orno[1,3]='111' or tdpur401.t_orno[1,4]='1126' )
```

Attempt at T-SQL query:

```
from    ttdpur401105 as tdpur401
inner join ttdpur400105 as tdpur400 on tdpur401.t_orno = tdpur400.t_orno 
left outer join tarpur002105 as arpur002 on arpur002.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno and arpur002.t_pono = tdpur401.t_pono
left outer join (ttdpur402105 as tdpur402 
                 left outer join (ttisfc001105 as tisfc001 
                                  left outer join ttcibd001105 as tcibd001a on tcibd001a.t_item = tisfc001.t_mitm
                                                                            and tisfc001.t_pdno = tdpur402.t_pdno) on tdpur402.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno)
left outer join ttcibd001105 as tcibd001 on tcibd001.t_item = tdpur401.t_item 

WHERE   tdpur401.t_otbp = ' WD005'
and ((tdpur401.t_oltp=1 AND tdpur401.t_qibo <>0) OR(tdpur401.t_oltp=4 AND tdpur401.t_qibo = 0 AND tdpur401.t_qidl<>tdpur401.t_qoor)) 
and tdpur401.t_fire <> 1
and (tdpur400.t_hdst<>25 AND tdpur400.t_hdst<>30 AND tdpur400.t_hdst<>40)        
and tdpur402.t_pono = tdpur402.t_pono   
and substring(tdpur401.t_orno,1,3)='111' or substring(tdpur401.t_orno, 1,4)='1126'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone's naming conventions leave much to be desired.  Also, a SELECT statement starts with SELECT; it feels funny looking at decapitated SQL.  It looks like you've got the general idea right.

```
SELECT *
  FROM      ttdpur401105 AS tdpur401
  JOIN      ttdpur400105 AS tdpur400 ON  tdpur401.t_orno = tdpur400.t_orno 
  LEFT JOIN tarpur002105 AS arpur002 ON  arpur002.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno 
                                     AND arpur002.t_pono = tdpur401.t_pono 
  LEFT JOIN ttcibd001105 AS tcibd001 ON  tcibd001.t_item = tdpur401.t_item 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
               FROM ttdpur402105 AS tdpur402
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                            FROM      ttisfc001105 AS tisfc001
                            LEFT JOIN ttcibd001105 AS tcibd001a
                              ON tcibd001a.t_item = tisfc001.t_mitm
                         )
                 ON tisfc001.t_pdno = tdpur402.t_pdno
            )
    ON tdpur402.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno 
   AND tdpur402.t_pono = tdpur402.t_pono   -- ??typo tdpur402.t_pono = tdpur401.t_pono
 WHERE   tdpur401.t_otbp = ' WD005' 
   AND ((tdpur401.t_oltp = 1 AND tdpur401.t_qibo <> 0) OR 
        (tdpur401.t_oltp = 4 AND tdpur401.t_qibo = 0 AND
         tdpur401.t_qidl <> tdpur401.t_qoor)) 
   AND   tdpur401.t_fire <> 1
   AND  (tdpur401.t_orno[1,3]='111' OR tdpur401.t_orno[1,4]='1126' )
   AND  (tdpur400.t_hdst <> 25 AND tdpur400.t_hdst <> 30 AND tdpur400.t_hdst <> 40)
```

You might be able to write it without those inner SELECT parts, just using more LEFT JOIN notations. I think  you'd need to use the parentheses to ensure the right interpretation (or, at the very least, I'd want to add the parentheses to explain to myself the interpretation).

The only issue left to worry about is that the old, non-standard Informix OUTER notation is not only syntactically different from the new, standard SQL notation but also produces different results under some circumstances.  Most of the time, you'll be OK.  But you should carefully scrutinize the results from your translated query to ensure that you get all the data you expect.  On the whole, you're likely to find that the standard SQL produces what you want (and the old notation may have produced rows that you didn't actually want).  But you *must* check carefully.

Clearly, I've not tested this code.  You might need to tag the sub-selects with an AS clause, and that might have ramifications for the join conditions.

---

Having seen [Andrey Gurinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949001/andrey-gurinov)'s comment about the `tdpur402.t_pono = tdpur402.t_pono` condition, I agree with him that it is odd (I missed it until scanning his answer).  It will evaluate to true unless `tdpur402.t_pono` is NULL.  I suspect a typo; one of the two '402' should be '401', but that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: The AS keyword is necessary and therefore complicates matter. Already I got a "The column move_item was specified multiple times for 'table_a'" error.

Comment: That's the difficulty with us not having the select-list and the schemas of the tables; we can't tell what you might need to pull from where.  You've listed some columns, but there are probably others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from    ttdpur401105 as tdpur401 
inner join ttdpur400105 as tdpur400 on tdpur401.t_orno = tdpur400.t_orno  
left outer join tarpur002105 as arpur002 
    on arpur002.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno and arpur002.t_pono = tdpur401.t_pono 
left outer join ttdpur402105 as tdpur402  
    on tdpur402.t_orno = tdpur401.t_orno 
left outer join ttisfc001105 as tisfc001  
    ON tisfc001.t_pdno = tdpur402.t_pdno
left outer join ttcibd001105 as tcibd001a 
    on tcibd001a.t_item = tisfc001.t_mitm 

left outer join ttcibd001105 as tcibd001 
    on tcibd001.t_item = tdpur401.t_item  

WHERE   tdpur401.t_otbp = ' WD005' 
and ((tdpur401.t_oltp=1 AND tdpur401.t_qibo <>0) OR(tdpur401.t_oltp=4 AND tdpur401.t_qibo = 0 AND tdpur401.t_qidl<>tdpur401.t_qoor))  
and tdpur401.t_fire <> 1 
and (tdpur400.t_hdst<>25 AND tdpur400.t_hdst<>30 AND tdpur400.t_hdst<>40)         
and tdpur402.t_pono = tdpur402.t_pono    
and substring(tdpur401.t_orno,1,3)='111' or substring(tdpur401.t_orno, 1,4)='1126'
```

And also you need to check this row:

```
and tdpur402.t_pono = tdpur402.t_pono
```

I'm a little confused about it.

Comment: It's not my code and I haven't heard why it's there. But yes, it boggled me as well.

Comment: By the way, your code worked. I just had to move tha tdpur402.t_pono line to the joins. However, Jonathan Leffler pointed some things that I had no idea I had to consider. If I could, I'd green check both of you :(

Comment: Hope I can gain points somewhere else. Looks like I'm in need more then Jonathan :)